# Stopping boost::asio::io_service::run() from concurrent destructor

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Can anybody explain me why this program does not terminate (see the comments)?

```
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

class Service {
public:
    ~Service() {
        std::cout << "Destroying...\n";
        io_service.post([this]() {
            std::cout << "clean and stop\n"; // does not get called
            // do some cleanup
            // ...
            io_service.stop();
            std::cout << "Bye!\n";
        });
        std::cout << "...destroyed\n"; // last printed line, blocks
    }

    void operator()() {
        io_service.run();
        std::cout << "run completed\n";
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::io_service::work work{io_service};
};

struct Test {
    void start() {
        f = std::async(std::launch::async, [this]() { service(); std::cout << "exiting thread\n";});
    }
    std::future<void> f;
    Service service;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    {
        Test test;
        test.start();

        std::string exit;
        std::cin >> exit;
    }

    std::cout << "exiting program\n"; // never printed
}
```

Comment: if three hours is not fast enough, perhaps you should hire someone :)

Answer (score 3):

The real issue is that destruction of `io_service` is (obviously) not thread-safe.

Just reset the work and join the thread. Optionally, set a flag so your IO operations know shutdown is in progress.

You Test and Service classes are trying to share responsibility for the IO service, that doesn't work. Here's much simplified, merging the classes and dropping the unused future.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f94dd8c775e1c42)**

The trick was to make the `work` object `optional<>`:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

struct Service {
    ~Service() {
        std::cout << "clean and stop\n";
        io_service.post([this]() {
            work.reset(); // let io_service run out of work
        });

        if (worker.joinable())
            worker.join();
    }

    void start() {
        assert(!worker.joinable());
        worker = std::thread([this] { io_service.run(); std::cout << "exiting thread\n";});
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    std::thread worker;
    boost::optional<boost::asio::io_service::work> work{io_service};
};

int main() {
    {
        Service test;
        test.start();

        std::cin.ignore(1024, '\n');
        std::cout << "Start shutdown\n";
    }

    std::cout << "exiting program\n"; // never printed
}
```

Prints

```
Start shutdown
clean and stop
exiting thread
exiting program
```

Comment: If I remember well I did try to reset the worker (it was an unique_ptr in my case).  Although it seems not useful from this simple example taken from the real case, the thing I need is to really call stop() as written in my question  before destroying the worker. I'll try again later, but it kept  crashing if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Martin Don't "remember". Just look at your code in the question. Work reset is not there (also, don't confuse `work` and `worker`). My code doesn't crash. Hope that helps.

Comment: Brilliant!  This is the only answer I've found on SO that actually stops my `io_service.run()`

Answer (score 2):

See here: [boost::asio hangs in resolver service destructor after throwing out of io_service::run()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324293/boostasio-hangs-in-resolver-service-destructor-after-throwing-out-of-io-servic?rq=1)

I think the trick here is to destroy the worker (the `work` member) before calling `io_service.stop()`. I.e. in this case the `work` could be an `unique_ptr`, and call `reset()` explicitly before stopping the service.

**EDIT**: The above helped me some time ago in my case, where the `ioservice::stop` didn't stop and was waiting for some dispatching events which never happened.

However I reproduced the problem you have on my machine and this seems to be a race condition inside `ioservice`, a race between `ioservice::post()` and the `ioservice` destruction code (`shutdown_service`). In particular, if the `shutdown_service()` is triggered before the `post()` notification wakes up the other thread, the `shutdown_service()` code removes the operation from the queue (and "destroys" it instead of calling it), therefore the lambda is never called then.

For now it seems to me that you'd need to call the `io_service.stop()` directly in the destructor, not postponed via the `post()` as that apparently doest not work here because of the race.

Comment: what does it mean before calling io_service.stop()? inside or outside the lamba? inside won't work as the lambda is not even called

Comment: See the update, there seems to be a race condition between `post()` and the destruction (`shutdown_service()`).

Comment: but postponing it after the cleanup was my real intention..so is this a bug in boost::asio? from the documentation I would have expected all the pending handlers to be called when work is destroyed

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, I also wasn't testing the newest Boost, but to me it seems that all the pending handlers are only executed when `stop()` is called; but if the service is destroyed without calling `stop()` first, the `shutdown_service()` cleans the queue not running the handlers (i.e. canceling them). So if the other thread did not manage to run all the handlers before, they are never executed then.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix the problem by rewriting your code like so:

```
class Service {
public:
    ~Service() {
        std::cout << "Destroying...\n";
        work.reset();
        std::cout << "...destroyed\n"; // last printed line, blocks
    }

    void operator()() {
        io_service.run();
        std::cout << "run completed\n";
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> work = std::make_unique<boost::asio::io_service::work>(io_service);
};
```

However, this is largely a bandaid solution.

The problem lies in your design ethos; specifically, in choosing not to tie the lifetime of the executing thread directly to the `io_service` object:

```
struct Test {
    void start() {
        f = std::async(std::launch::async, [this]() { service(); std::cout << "exiting thread\n";});
    }
    std::future<void> f; //Constructed First, deleted last
    Service service; //Constructed second, deleted first
};
```

In this particular scenario, the thread is going to continue to attempt to execute `io_service.run()` past the lifetime of the `io_service` object itself. If more than the basic `work` object were executing on the service, you very quickly begin to deal with undefined behavior with calling member functions of deleted objects.

You could reverse the order of the member objects in `Test`:

```
struct Test {
    void start() {
        f = std::async(std::launch::async, [this]() { service(); std::cout << "exiting thread\n";});
    }
    Service service;
    std::future<void> f;
};
```

But it still represents a significant design flaw.

The way that I usually implement anything which uses `io_service` is to tie its lifetime to the threads that are actually going to be executing on it.

```
class Service {
public:
    Service(size_t num_of_threads = 1) :
        work(std::make_unique<boost::asio::io_service::work>(io_service))
    {
        for (size_t thread_index = 0; thread_index < num_of_threads; thread_index++) {
            threads.emplace_back([this] {io_service.run(); });
        }
    }

    ~Service() {
        work.reset();
        for (std::thread & thread : threads) 
            thread.join();
    }
private:
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> work;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
};
```

Now, if you have any infinite loops active on any of these threads, you'll still need to make sure you properly clean those up, but at least the code specific to the operation of this `io_service` is cleaned up correctly.

Comment: Why did you introduce more worker threads? That might be completely inappropriate for the OP

Comment: _"If more than the basic work object were executing on the service, you very quickly begin to deal with undefined behavior"_ is misleading. It's UB regardless

Comment: I actually like your constructive suggestion - with the threads container and all, but the first part of the answer (the "band-aid") really needs to go. It's not a bandaid and it doesn't help to explain the issue.